# .net MVC / datatables.net ServerSide Processing - circular reference Error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatables

I need 2 dimensional JSON Object for Server Side Processing DataTables
but i get this error on serializing. Thank you for help

ERROR A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type ‘System.Reflection.RuntimeModule’.

with this code:

```
DataTable data = AlleArtikelWork.GetAllArtikel(myLimit);
var myjson = Json(data);
myjson.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
JsonResult rtnjson = Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data= myjson }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
return rtnjson;
```

Same Error with this:

```
DataTable data = AlleArtikelWork.GetAllArtikel(myLimit);
JsonResult rtnjson = Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data= data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
return rtnjson;
```

thank you

Comment: Don't use a `DataTable`. Create a model containing only the properties you need and pass that.

Comment: this might help : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stephen said in the comments, it's probably a bad idea to try and serialize the DataTable directly.  Even if it didn't throw that error, it's still a bad idea because your final JSON string would contain all the public properties of the DataTable and DataRow classes themselves (data.CaseSensitive, data.IsInitialized, data.DesignMode, etc etc etc), which is just going to be useless junk data to whomever is receiving your serialized object.

Better practice is to create your own classes that contain **only** the data you actually **need** to serialize, and write a little tedious code to build an array of those objects by using the data from your GetAllArtikel() method.

Now, none of this has anything to do with why you're getting that actual **error**.  If you want to understand why that error happens, it's because, somewhere in all those public properties of the DataTable class that it's trying to serialize, you've got a situation like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
  public ClassB ObjectB;
}

public class ClassB
{
  public ClassA ObjectA;
}

public JsonResult SomeMethod()
{
  var objA = new ClassA();
  var objB = new ClassB();

  objA.ObjectB = objB;
  objB.ObjectA = objA;

  return Json(objA);
}
```

So, now we've got two objects which **have public properties pointing at each other**, this is the root cause of your error.  Normally this situation is perfectly fine, BUT, for serializing it can be problem.  The serializer is going to recursively navigate through all public properties of objA, end up in a situation where it's trying to build the JSON string like this:

```
{
  "ObjectB" : {
    "ObjectA": {
      "ObjectB": {
        "ObjectA": {
          "ObjectB": {
            .. and so on, infinitely!
```

Eventually, the serializer is smart enough to realize that it's going in circles, and throws the "circular reference was detected" exception that you saw.

There are ways to customize the .net JSON serializer so that it will handle this situation differently (instead of throwing the error), but for your situation, I would take Stephen's advice and not even serialize a DataTable directly at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for explaining the Problem itself

solution: 
Converting the DataTable into Dictonary and call the same Json Function

```
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> TableToDict( DataTable table)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return rows;
    }
```

and return the JsonResult:

```
JsonResult rtnjson = Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = TableToDict(data)}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

works goot thx